# problem while booting when the uImage is replaced

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, driver, u-boot

I made a small change in the driver code in the kernel, built the kernel (uImage).

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- uImage
```

Replaced the uImage in the ISO (extracted it and rebuilt). But I get the following error while booting. I even reverted the code changes, only built and replaced the uImage. Still the error is present. I am not understanding the problem. Even searched the internet, but could not succeed with all the solutions.

Can anyone please guide me. The pre-built kernel uImage works fine.

```
U-Boot 2009.08 (Jan 11 2019 - 08:37:07)

CPU: Freescale i.MX6 family TO0.0 at 996 MHz
Thermal sensor with ratio = 189
Temperature:   20 C, calibration data 0x5a94f97d
mx6q pll1: 996MHz
mx6q pll2: 528MHz
mx6q pll3: 480MHz
mx6q pll8: 50MHz
ipg clock     : 66000000Hz
ipg per clock : 66000000Hz
uart clock    : 80000000Hz
cspi clock    : 60000000Hz
ahb clock     : 132000000Hz
axi clock   : 264000000Hz
emi_slow clock: 132000000Hz
ddr clock     : 528000000Hz
usdhc1 clock  : 198000000Hz
usdhc2 clock  : 198000000Hz
usdhc3 clock  : 198000000Hz
usdhc4 clock  : 198000000Hz
nfc clock     : 24000000Hz
Board: MX6-IAVS:[POR] - Built under Wind River Linux
Boot Device: UNKNOWN
I2C:   ready
DRAM:   2 GB
MMC:   status 0
FSL_ESDHC: 0
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   got MAC address from IIM: 9c:28:bf:d2:c1:c7
FEC0 [PRIME]
autoboot in 5 seconds
(Re)start USB...
USB:   Register 10011 NbrPorts 1
USB EHCI 1.00
scanning bus for devices... 2 USB Device(s) found
       scanning bus for storage devices... 1 Storage Device(s) found

Loading from USB device 0, partition 0: Name: usbda0  Type: U-Boot
   Image Name:   EoLTesting
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Multi-File Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    4708687 Bytes =  4.5 MB
   Load Address: 10008000
   Entry Point:  10008000
   Contents:
      Image 0: 4283224 Bytes =  4.1 MB
      Image 1: 425451 Bytes = 415.5 kB
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
stopping USB..
## Copying part 1 from legacy image at 10800000 ...
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 10800000 ...
   Image Name:   EoLTesting
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Multi-File Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    4708687 Bytes =  4.5 MB
   Load Address: 10008000
   Entry Point:  10008000
   Contents:
      Image 0: 4283224 Bytes =  4.1 MB
      Image 1: 425451 Bytes = 415.5 kB
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 12000000 ...
   Image Name:   
   Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    425387 Bytes = 415.4 kB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Multi-File Image ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...

Booting Linux on physical CPU 0
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Linux version 3.4.91-rt56-WR5.0.1.26_preempt-rt (chukkaa@nul6136u) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Wind River Linux Sourcery CodeBench 4.6a-148) ) #4 SMP PREEMPT RT Tue Jul 12 13:18:56 CEST 2016
CPU: ARMv7 Processor [412fc09a] revision 10 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache

Truncating RAM at 10000000-8fffffff to -7b7fffff (vmalloc region overlap).
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writealloc
CPU identified as i.MX6Q, silicon rev 1.5
PERCPU: Embedded 9 pages/cpu @81a75000 s16256 r8192 d12416 u36864
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 432784
Kernel command line: root=/dev/ram0 rw nosmp video=mxcfb0:dev=lcd,800x600-32@60,if=RGB24
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
allocated 15851520 bytes of page_cgroup
please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
Memory: 752MB 952MB = 1704MB total
Memory: 1700200k/1700200k available, 61080k reserved, 0K highmem
Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xec000000 - 0xfb000000   ( 240 MB)
    lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xeb800000   (1720 MB)
    modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
      .text : 0x80008000 - 0x80b789b8   (11715 kB)
      .init : 0x80b79000 - 0x80bc2f80   ( 296 kB)
      .data : 0x80bc4000 - 0x80c33a58   ( 447 kB)
       .bss : 0x80c33a7c - 0x80cdf06c   ( 686 kB)
Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
NR_IRQS:436
sched_clock: 32 bits at 3000kHz, resolution 333ns, wraps every 1431655ms
arm_max_freq=1GHz
twd_local_timer_register failed -6
MXC_Early serial console at MMIO 0x21f0000 (options '115200')
bootconsole [ttymxc0] enabled
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,0)
User configuration error - no valid root filesystem found
Kernel panic - not syncing: Invalid configuration from end user prevents continuing
[<80017c70>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8) from [<80542f64>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24)
[<80542f64>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24) from [<8054328c>] (panic+0x138/0x298)
[<8054328c>] (panic+0x138/0x298) from [<80afff60>] (change_floppy+0x0/0xec)
[<80afff60>] (change_floppy+0x0/0xec) from [<80b000b4>] (mount_root+0x68/0x6c)
[<80b000b4>] (mount_root+0x68/0x6c) from [<80b00250>] (prepare_namespace+0x198/0x1dc)
[<80b00250>] (prepare_namespace+0x198/0x1dc) from [<80affb50>] (kernel_init+0x294/0x29c)
[<80affb50>] (kernel_init+0x294/0x29c) from [<8000f4e4>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
CPU3: stopping
[<80017c70>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8) from [<80542f64>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24)
[<80542f64>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24) from [<80014e18>] (handle_IPI+0x170/0x1a8)
[<80014e18>] (handle_IPI+0x170/0x1a8) from [<80008544>] (gic_handle_irq+0x64/0x68)
[<80008544>] (gic_handle_irq+0x64/0x68) from [<805483c0>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70)
Exception stack(0xea0f5f58 to 0xea0f5fa0)
5f40:                                                       00000001 80000093
5f60: f2a02000 8001f200 80bb77c8 80b67408 805505d0 ea0f4000 ea0f4030 80b6c650
5f80: ea0f4000 ea0f5fac ea0f5fb0 ea0f5fa0 8000f5b8 8000f5bc 60000013 ffffffff
[<805483c0>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70) from [<8000f5bc>] (default_idle+0x48/0x4c)
[<8000f5bc>] (default_idle+0x48/0x4c) from [<8000f8f4>] (cpu_idle+0xdc/0x110)
[<8000f8f4>] (cpu_idle+0xdc/0x110) from [<8053f730>] (secondary_start_kernel+0x124/0x12c)
[<8053f730>] (secondary_start_kernel+0x124/0x12c) from [<1053ed14>] (0x1053ed14)
CPU1: stopping
[<80017c70>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8) from [<80542f64>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24)
[<80542f64>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24) from [<80014e18>] (handle_IPI+0x170/0x1a8)
[<80014e18>] (handle_IPI+0x170/0x1a8) from [<80008544>] (gic_handle_irq+0x64/0x68)
[<80008544>] (gic_handle_irq+0x64/0x68) from [<805483c0>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70)
Exception stack(0xea0b1f58 to 0xea0b1fa0)
1f40:                                                       00000001 80000093
1f60: f2a02000 8001f200 80bb77c8 80b67408 805505d0 ea0b0000 ea0b0030 80b6c650
1f80: ea0b0000 ea0b1fac ea0b1fb0 ea0b1fa0 8000f5b8 8000f5bc 60000013 ffffffff
[<805483c0>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70) from [<8000f5bc>] (default_idle+0x48/0x4c)
[<8000f5bc>] (default_idle+0x48/0x4c) from [<8000f8f4>] (cpu_idle+0xdc/0x110)
[<8000f8f4>] (cpu_idle+0xdc/0x110) from [<8053f730>] (secondary_start_kernel+0x124/0x12c)
[<8053f730>] (secondary_start_kernel+0x124/0x12c) from [<1053ed14>] (0x1053ed14)
CPU2: stopping
[<80017c70>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8) from [<80542f64>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24)
[<80542f64>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24) from [<80014e18>] (handle_IPI+0x170/0x1a8)
[<80014e18>] (handle_IPI+0x170/0x1a8) from [<80008544>] (gic_handle_irq+0x64/0x68)
[<80008544>] (gic_handle_irq+0x64/0x68) from [<805483c0>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70)
Exception stack(0xea0e3f58 to 0xea0e3fa0)
3f40:                                                       00000001 80000093
3f60: f2a02000 8001f200 80bb77c8 80b67408 805505d0 ea0e2000 ea0e2030 80b6c650
3f80: ea0e2000 ea0e3fac ea0e3fb0 ea0e3fa0 8000f5b8 8000f5bc 60000013 ffffffff
[<805483c0>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70) from [<8000f5bc>] (default_idle+0x48/0x4c)
[<8000f5bc>] (default_idle+0x48/0x4c) from [<8000f8f4>] (cpu_idle+0xdc/0x110)
[<8000f8f4>] (cpu_idle+0xdc/0x110) from [<8053f730>] (secondary_start_kernel+0x124/0x12c)
[<8053f730>] (secondary_start_kernel+0x124/0x12c) from [<1053ed14>] (0x1053ed14)
```

EDIT:
It is an imx ARM controller. I used the mkisofs tool to extract and rebuild the ISO file for ARM. If I just extract and rebuild the old ISO, it works fine.

I used the same configuration file from the old kernel.

Boootloader (u-boot) boots from the "ubootImage" from the ISO in USB.
ubootImage is a multiimage file comprising of the uImage and an initrd.
This step is successful.

After this the init script of the initrd, mounts the rootfs in the iso image and chroots to it, and tries to load an another kernel and initrd using kexec. This initrd (different to the one above in ubootImage) has an init script which mounts the rootfs in the iso image and chroots to it and just runs the bash to present bash shell.
This is where it fails, basically kexec fails. I do not know how kexec loads the initrd and uImage to memory. If there is
a problem with decompressed kernel overwritting the initrd.

Comment: welcome!  This question might be improved by adding some more context.  For instance, what hardware are you trying to boot this kernel from? How did you rebuild the ISO? Did you use the kernel configuration from the prebuilt kernel when you tried to build your own?

Comment: Seems you might got ramdisk overriden by decomressed kernel, for example. Something wrong with your initramdisk or its address in memory or U-Boot configuration for it. I also recommend to update U-Boot. You are using way too old one.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191607/problem-while-booting-when-the-uimage-is-replaced